# Proof of strong limit $\displaystyle s-\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} (I+i\varepsilon A)^{-1}=I$

Tags: operator-theory, unbounded-operators, self-adjoint-operators

Let $A$ be an unbounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$, I was wondering if there was an 'elementary proof', i.e. that doesn't use the full functional calculus, of the strong limit :

$$\displaystyle s-\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} (I+i\varepsilon A)^{-1}=I$$

where $I$ is the identity map of $H$.

I was hoping that something like this might work:
let $u\in \mathcal{D}(A)$, set $y_\varepsilon=(I+i\varepsilon A)^{-1}u$, $y_\varepsilon$ is uniformly bounded and: $(I+i\varepsilon A)y_\varepsilon=u$ for any $\varepsilon>0$. If one can show that $i\varepsilon Ay_\varepsilon\to 0$ when $\varepsilon \to 0$ then the result follows, but showing this seems to be pretty much the same as the original problem.

Edit: I mean by $s-\lim$ a limit in the strong operator topology.

Comment: Your $1$ should be $I$.

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected that now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following result:

If $\|T-I\|<1$, then $T^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(I-T)^k$, which implies that $\|T^{-1}\|\leq \dfrac{1}{1-\|I-T\|}$.

For small $\varepsilon$, let $T=I+i\varepsilon A$. Then one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\|(I+i\varepsilon A)^{-1}-I\|\\
&=&\|(I-(I+i\varepsilon A))(I+i\varepsilon A)^{-1}\|\\
&=&|\varepsilon|\|A(I+i\varepsilon A)^{-1}\|\\
&\le&|\varepsilon|\|A\|\|(I+i\varepsilon A)^{-1}\|\\
&\le&\varepsilon\|A\|\frac{1}{1-\|I-(I+i\varepsilon A)\|}\\
&=&\varepsilon\|A\|\frac{1}{1-|\varepsilon| \|A\|\|}.
\end{eqnarray}
Now it is easy to see
$$ \lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\|(I+i\varepsilon A)^{-1}-I\}\|=0 $$
or equivalently
$$\displaystyle s-\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} (I+i\varepsilon A)^{-1}=I.$$

Comment: This works when $A$ is bounded, and if I’m not mistaken the convergence is even uniform, but what if A is unbounded? The inequality on the fourth line doesn’t hold any more and although it can be replaced by $||A(I+i\varepsilon A)^{-1}||\leq \frac{1}{|\varepsilon|}$ this isn’t enough:(